# Recreating user, IIS application pool and website error

Tags: deployment, iis-7, web, application-pool, was

We are creating windows user, application pool using this user and website using the application pool in IIS 7, but if we delete these after creation and recreate them again the application pool start fails with the following error:

*The Windows Process Activation Service failed to create a worker process for the application pool 'TestUserPool'. The data field contains the error number.*

The Event ID is 5022 and the error number 80070005 which means ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED as we found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734972%28WS.10%29.aspx)

The strange thing is that changing the pool name, changing the application pool user or restarting the IIS fixes the problem. We had this issues when doing all this programmatically, but the same thing cannot be reproduced manually. 
The problem is that we need to add this functionality to an installer, but if you uninstall the site and then reinstall you will receive "Service Unavailable" until you restart your IIS server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same error. My application pool is stopped as soon as the first request comes in.

Comment: I've got the same error as well. same symptoms